# in-house app will not deploy OTA, possibly a signing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, macos-monterey

I know this seems to be a issue with signing the application using Apples new Code Signature Format and there have been various fixes going round but they don't seem to apply/fix my issue. I'm seeing this with in one of our InHouse apps, our other apps have compiled/installed/run on iOS devices with no issues but this one app is proving stubborn. I've also tried creating a completely new project and strangely I'm seeing this issue with the new app as well.

Im running Monterey 12.0.1 with Xcode 13.1. The app is targeting iOS 15, it builds and runs on device running iOS 15.1.1 from Xcode fine. I've Archived and Exported with automatic code signing like all our other apps.

Extracting the .ipa file and running `codesign -dvvvvv ./Payload/AppName.app` on the .app file gives:

```
CodeDirectory v=20400
Page size=4096
    -7=f98e5aa1b62669f050c7f71f4a36834a291ba177b4b8ce8a746de324098ce336
    -6=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    -5=d1343f304ebed50ddd6d18e38b6602a00cd6e784e02bfe9c5aef1240ace1734e
    -4=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    -3=fdec1782c98ec9832e5641b126404722b9bcd1e339da35f46766afae8b44dde6
    -2=3fe1b0c56bb490dbc4f2e446ce534fcf547abecd63ffa198978b9615f28ecff6
```

and the `embedded.mobileprovision` contains:

```
<key>DER-Encoded-Profile</key>
<data>MIINkAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIINgTCC...</data>
```

Which according to the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format) it is signed correctly.

I have also tried creating a new provisioning profile via the Apple developer website and manually selecting signing it when exporting the .ipa from the Archive.

If I drag the .ipa onto the phone in the devices window the app installs and runs.

However, If I install the app OTA by opening this link in Safari `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://website.com/manifest.plist`

I get the "Developer needs to update the app..." message.

I've also tried a different iPhone running iOS 15.0, but the issue persists.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the minimum iOS version does your app and embedded frameworks supports?

Comment: Everything is targeting 15.

Comment: Including precompiled frameworks?

Comment: Unless you have already done so, I would suggest checking the device log. Usually, there you get more information on what exactly failed while launching the app, or at least the error message might help you narrow down the issue.